# KeyFactory.createKey() Is this the correct way of storing data in Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

each user can have many questions. questions can only have one user. is the following correct

```
Key questionKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Questions", userId);
Entity questionEntity = new Entity("Question", questionKey);
questionEntity.setProperty("questionCategory", questionCategory);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given usage is wrong. For the question, you are creating key using kind and userid . This implies the corresponding entity is of `Kind="Questions"` and `id=userid` and no parents. This is wrong and you will start getting errors once you have more than 1 question for a user as they will all have the same key.

Ideally what you need is that for a question entity, declare its kind as question and parent as the user as follows :

1, If using manually generated id or name for a question , then :

```
Key questionKey = KeyFactory.createKey(userkey, "Questions", questionidorname);
```

2, If using app engine's auto generate id, then no need create key, instead create entity as:

```
Entity questionEntity = new Entity("Questions",
      userkey)
```

Here userkey is the key of a user entity